# Как отдать большой файл пользователю без ожидания его формирования на сервере

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Сейчас в контроллере примерно такой код:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage exportCSV()
{
    string csvString = model.getAllInCSV();

    var response = Request.CreateResponse();
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    response.Content = new StringContent(csvString, Encoding.GetEncoding("WINDOWS-1251"));
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = "foo.csv"
    };

    return response;
}
```

csvString  генерируется примерно пару минут, есть ли способ сразу отдать файл на загрузку пользователю? т.к. сейчас если пользователь нажмет на ссылку загрузки, и в течении времени пока формируется файл перейдет на другую страницу загрузки соответственно не произойдет.

Comment: А вы можете получить CSV постепенно, в виде потока?

Comment: Такой подход как тут [Writing to Output Stream from Action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943122/writing-to-output-stream-from-action), с использованием FileGeneratingResult может подойти.

Comment: @PrimusSingularis это MVC, а тут Web API

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать сделать так, но не факт, что это решит проблему.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage exportCSV()
{

    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = "foo.csv"
    };
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    response.Content = new PushStreamContent((stream, content, transport) => 
    {
        try
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("WINDOWS-1251")))
            {
                string csvString = model.getAllInCSV();
                writer.Write(csvString);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Close();
        }
    });

    return response;
}
```

Клиент может всё равно успеть перейти на другую страницу, пока не начнётся запись данных в stream. Думаю, есть смысл решать эту проблему с клиентской стороны, отправляя ajax запрос, и показывая какое либо уведомление.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, чтобы сразу отдать его надо сразу сформировать. Тут или сначала получать команду на формирование, после чего отдавать (например первый запрос идёт на формирование типа GenerateCSV, который формирует временный файл, и отдаёт его имя, запрашивать его аяксом, и писать пользователю что ждёмс на странице, а потом сразу загружать), либо попробовать в контент запихнуть что-нибудь типа потока и формировать файл в поток, а не на диск.

Comment: Вот по поводу потоков, в какую сторону гуглить, где посмотреть примеры? Я так понял нужно использовать async, отдавать stream из контроллера и писать в него с стороны приложения после этого?

Comment: не думаю что это хорошая идея. посмотрите эту ссылку http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072814/c-sharp-asp-net-write-file-to-client основной принцип - это открыть ответ и писать в буфер в том же методе. Если это делать асинхронно, то билеберда получится

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse(v=vs.110).aspx тут свойтва Buffer и BufferOutput насколько я понимаю, которые отвечают за способ отдачи ответа клиенту

Comment: @Чад зачем вы даете ответы про ASP.NET Web Forms, когда вопрос задан про Web API?

Comment: "не думаю, что это хорошая идея" - это лучший подход, который можно использовать

Comment: Хорошая идея, делать асинк метод в асинкном методе, который всё равно ждёт выполнения асинк метода?